# creating docker-compose to handle multi arch

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the below code.I need `linux/arm64` and `linux/arm/v7` arch images. My understanding is `docker-compose create` with the `platform` option creates multi-arch images. But it not work as I expect.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4000:3000'
    platform: linux/arm64
    platform: linux/arm/v7
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building two differently tagged docker images with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017559/building-two-differently-tagged-docker-images-with-docker-compose)

Comment: @kshayBarad did you found any solution ?

Comment: It's odd, the platform attribute doesn't appear in the v3 spec: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/ But it does show on the latest spec in GitHub https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#platform. It also shows in the older v2 spec https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/